# How To Get All The Contiguous Substrings Of A String In Python?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, substring

Here is my code, but I want a better solution, how do you think about the problem?

```
def get_all_substrings(string):
  length = len(string)
  alist = []
  for i in xrange(length):
    for j in xrange(i,length):
      alist.append(string[i:j + 1]) 
  return alist

print get_all_substring('abcde')
```

Comment: Better in what sense and what is the problem with this solution?

Comment: Maybe more faster? Or not so simple.

Comment: @user2357112, OP's native language is obviously not English, and it seems like OP is saying "or maybe it's not so simple to make this function faster".

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The only improvement I could think of is, to use list comprehension like this

```
def get_all_substrings(input_string):
  length = len(input_string)
  return [input_string[i:j+1] for i in xrange(length) for j in xrange(i,length)]

print get_all_substrings('abcde')
```

The timing comparison between, yours and mine

```
def get_all_substrings(string):
  length = len(string)
  alist = []
  for i in xrange(length):
    for j in xrange(i,length):
      alist.append(string[i:j + 1]) 
  return alist

def get_all_substrings_1(input_string):
  length = len(input_string)
  return [input_string[i:j + 1] for i in xrange(length) for j in xrange(i,length)]

from timeit import timeit
print timeit("get_all_substrings('abcde')", "from __main__ import get_all_substrings")
# 3.33308315277
print timeit("get_all_substrings_1('abcde')", "from __main__ import get_all_substrings_1")
# 2.67816185951
```

Comment: If you're doing timeit, you might find `range` is quicker than `xrange` for such a small range

Comment: @gnibbler I get slightly bigger number when I use `range` :(

Comment: @thefourtheye, don't be sad - it's a good thing if there isn't any longer a penalty to using xrange for small ranges (apart from the Python3 thing)

Comment: I'm guessing the time complexity of this is O(n log n)?

Answer (score 17):

can be done concisely with `itertools.combinations`

```
from itertools import combinations

def get_all_substrings_2(string):
    length = len(string) + 1
    return [string[x:y] for x, y in combinations(range(length), r=2)]
```

Comment: This is much more performant than the currently selected answer too.

Answer (score 10):

You could write it as a generator to save storing all the strings in memory at once if you don't need to

```
def get_all_substrings(string):
    length = len(string)
    for i in xrange(length):
        for j in xrange(i + 1, length + 1):
            yield(string[i:j]) 

for i in get_all_substrings("abcde"):
    print i
```

you can still make a list if you really need one

```
alist = list(get_all_substrings("abcde"))
```

The function can be reduced to return a generator expression

```
def get_all_substrings(s):
    length = len(s)
    return (s[i: j] for i in xrange(length) for j in xrange(i + 1, length + 1))
```

Or of course you can change two characters to return a list if you don't care about memory

```
def get_all_substrings(s):
    length = len(s)
    return [s[i: j] for i in xrange(length) for j in xrange(i + 1, length + 1)]
```

Comment: This saved me, I was getting a memory error, I did some searching, found your solution and it solved my issue as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I've never been fond of `range(len(seq))`, how about using enumerate and just using the index value:

```
def indexes(seq, start=0):
    return (i for i,_ in enumerate(seq, start=start))

def gen_all_substrings(s):
    return (s[i:j] for i in indexes(s) for j in indexes(s[i:], i+1))

def get_all_substrings(string):
    return list(gen_all_substrings(string))

print(get_all_substrings('abcde'))
```

Answer (score 4):

Python 3

```
s='abc'
list(s[i:j+1] for i in range (len(s)) for j in range(i,len(s)))

['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'b', 'bc', 'c']
```

Comment: This duplicates other answers. Have you added anything to the top 2 answers from 2-4 years ago?

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.permutations` to generate all pairs of possible start and end indexes,
and filter out only those where the start index is less than then end index. Then
use these pairs to return slices of the original string.

```
from itertools import permutations

def gen_all_substrings(s):
    lt = lambda pair: pair[0] < pair[1]
    index_pairs = filter(lt, permutations(range(len(s)+1), 2))
    return (s[i:j] for i,j in index_pairs)

def get_all_substrings(s):
    return list(gen_all_substrings(s))

print(get_all_substrings('abcde'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
def get_all_substrings(string):
   length = len(string)+1
   return [string[x:y] for x in range(length) for y in range(length) if string[x:y]]

print get_all_substring('abcde')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using 2-D matrix approach

```
p = "abc"
a = list(p)
b = list(p)
c = list(p)
count = 0
for i in range(0,len(a)):
       dump = a[i]
            for j in range(0, len(b)):
                if i < j:
                    c.append(dump+b[j])
                    dump = dump + b[j]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the substrings sorted by the length:

```
s = 'abcde'
def allSubstrings(s: str) -> List[str]:
    length = len(s)
    mylist = []
    for i in range(1, length+1):
        for j in range(length-i+1):
            mylist.append(s[j:j+i])
    return mylist

print(allSubstrings(s))

['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'de', 'abc', 'bcd', 'cde', 'abcd', 'bcde', 'abcde']
```

Comment: Comprehensions are *significantly* faster than loops.