# Finding unique strings of characters in each sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, unique, bioinformatics

I am trying to create a program that has multiple sequences of tRNA stored as a dictionary. I have set up my code to extract and store the sequences and the specific names associated with the sequences as:

```
class Unique():
    def __init__(self, seq = ''):
        for s in range(len(seq)):
            for e in range(s + 1, len(seq) + 1):
                self.add(seq[s:e])
        self.head = head
        self.sequence = seq
        self.original = {}

    def cleaner(self):
        for (header, sequence) in myReader.readFasta():
            clean = sequence.replace('-','').replace('_','')
            self.original[self.head] = clean
        return self.original

    def sites(self):
        Unique.cleaner(self)
```

I am calling on the sites function (which is why it runs cleaner as the first step), but I am lost on how I can go about writing code to find unique strings in each stored sequence.

As an example if I have 2 sets of Sequences:

1. `UCGUUAGC`
2. `AGCGCAUU`

The program would be able to tell me that the first sequence's unique string is `UCG` and the second's is `AGC`, since `UCG` is ONLY present in the first sequence and `AGC` is only present in the second.

EDIT: What I mean by unique sequence: Any strand of the sequence I can see and automatically know which sequence it came from. So if the strand `UCGA` only exists in one sequence, it is counted and saved as a unique strand associated with that sequence.

The sequences extracted look like this:

```
GAGAGAGACAUAGAGGDUAUGAPGPPGG'UUGAACCAAUAGUAGGGGGUPCG"UUCCUUCCUUUCUUACCA
```

Comment: `CGU` is also a unique string in the first sequence, no?

Comment: There are many unique sequences not named. You should clarify your definition of unique and a sequence. Is it always 3 characters? Can it start at any point?

Comment: @KlausD.it doesn't necessarily have to be 3 characters, just any combination of characters that is unique to each sequence. I hope my edit clarifies what I meant

Comment: So, just starting with the U it would me `UC`, `UCG`, `UCGU`, `UCGUU`, , `UCGUUA`, `UCGUUAG` and `UCGUUAGC` for sequence 1?

Comment: @KlausD. - Think you missed `UA`, `UUA`, `UUAG`, and some others :)

Comment: Overall yes, that is basically it, although I would rather have it spit out the answers as `UC`, `CGU`, `GUU`, etc.. as they don't just add a letter or two to the first unique string found. But if I can't do that, thats fine too.

Comment: I just noticed `AGC` is in both of your sequences, so your example is a bit wrong.

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand correctly, you want all substrings of sequence A that do not exist in sequence B.

This can be easily achieved using a [set complement or difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)).

And [I "stole" some code from another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469997/how-to-get-all-the-contiguous-substrings-of-a-string-in-python).

```
def get_all_substrings(input_string):
  length = len(input_string)
  return [input_string[i:j+1] for i in xrange(length) for j in xrange(i,length)]

# convert these to sets to remove duplicate substrings
seq1 = set(get_all_substrings('UCGUUAGC')) 
seq2 = set(get_all_substrings('AGCGCAUU'))

unique_seq1 = seq1 - seq2 # those sequences that are in seq1, and not in seq2
unique_seq2 = seq2 - seq1 # those sequences that are in seq2, and not in seq1
```

**UPDATE:**
As pointed out in the comments, the `get_all_substrings` method I copied will eat away at memory for large strings, this version is more perfomant in that it lazily gets the next substring

```
def get_all_substrings(string):
    length = len(string)
    for i in xrange(length):
        for j in xrange(i + 1, length + 1):
            yield(string[i:j])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! Just one question: would this work in an automated way? since I have way more than 2 sequences in my actual program. So when comparing seq1, it would compare it with like 50+ other sequences.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - the generator version is in that link to the other post, but I think having the list readily available is okay. And `a.difference(b)` is equivalent to `a - b`

Comment: @cricket_007, `a.difference(get_all_substrings('AGCGCAUU')))` is not the same , if you have large amounts of data your code won't fare too well, if you want to find what is unique to both symmetric_difference would do

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - of course that isn't the same, `get_all_substrings` returns a list, not a set

Comment: @cricket_007 do you know how the method call actually  works? You should maybe read the docs on python sets

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - yes :) It is a doubly-nested for loop with `O(n^2)` runtime that generates all substrings of the given string. The return value is a list that is stored in memory. I understand that using a generator is better and doing so would allow the use of `a.difference(get_all_substrings('AGCGCAUU')))`. Am I done being interviewed, now?

Comment: Thank you both for helping out. I'm trying to convert the manual code cricket provided so I can make it automated for multiple sequences. Hopefully I can get it done without a problem haha

Comment: using a list also allows `a.difference(....`,  I think pointing out that your code can be optimized greatly is not  considered to be an interview, you also only needed to using parens  `(input_string[i:j+1] for i in xrange(length) for j in xrange(i,length))`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - Ah, didn't realize generator comprehension was exactly like list comprehension. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @cricket_007 I tried to feed sequences into get_all_substrings using a for loop, but all the outputs of substrings are one letter long. Why is this happening?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Like you have a list of sequences you are iterating over and passing them into `get_all_substrings` only returns substrings of a single character? That could only happen if the sequence you give it is only one character.

Comment: I have all the sequences saved in a dictionary. I made a for loop that that for every sequence in the dictionary, it would run get_all_substrings with that sequence and then I told it to print the substrings. For each sequence it ran, it outputted 1 letter for the substrings. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Should you have the sequences in a list? Not sure what your keys or values would be for your dictionary. Also make sure you are iterating over the strings rather than the characters in the strings.