# Split string of integers to all possible list of numbers

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, split

I have a string of integers e.g. `s = "1234"` I want to split it to the individual sequential combinations of integers `split = [ 1234, 1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 123, 23, 234, 34 ]` How can I code this in Python?

What i tried:

```
for i in range(0,len(number)-1):
x =["" + number[j] for j in range(i, len(number))]
print(x)
```

Output:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
['2', '3', '4', '5']
['3', '4', '5']
['4', '5']
```

Comment: Are *duplicates* allowed? What is the amswer for, say, `1212`? Is it [1212, 121, 212, 12, 21, 12, 1, 2, 1, 2]` or `[1212, 121, 212, 12, 21, 1, 2]` only?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements)

Comment: I'm sorry for not making my question clear enough but  I need the combinations to be sequential  in string `1234` combinations for `2` should only be `23, 234` ignoring `21 and 24`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) library combined with [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> s = "1234"
>>> [int(''.join(x)) for i in range(len(s)) for x in combinations(s, i + 1)]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 13, 14, 23, 24, 34, 123, 124, 134, 234, 1234]
```

**update**
As you need only sequential combinations, you can use all substrings from the string (using [How To Get All The Contiguous Substrings Of A String In Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469997/how-to-get-all-the-contiguous-substrings-of-a-string-in-python)):

```
>>> l = len(s)
>>> [int(s[i:j+1]) for i in range(l) for j in range(i,l)]
[1, 12, 123, 1234, 2, 23, 234, 3, 34, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need all the combinations, so you can use `itertools.combinations` and a generator expression in order to generate all of them:

```
In [25]: from itertools import combinations
In [26]: list(''.join(sub) for i in range(1, len(s) + 1) for sub in combinations(s, i))
Out[26]: 
['1',
 '2',
 '3',
 '4',
 '12',
 '13',
 '14',
 '23',
 '24',
 '34',
 '123',
 '124',
 '134',
 '234',
 '1234']
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what I really needed was  a sequential combination lists so elements `13, 14, 134 ` etc. should be ignored in my case

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for somethng like this:

```
stringA = "1234";
lenA = len(stringA);

# Loop through the number of times stringA is long.
for n in range(lenA):
    print("---");
    # Loop through string, print part of the string.
    for x in range(lenA-n):
        print(stringA[n:n + (x+1)])
```

I suggest having a look at substrings, that is what I also do in my example above. 
[Link](https://www.dotnetperls.com/substring-python)