# How to find and check if any sub-string and its reverse exist in given string?

Tags: string, algorithm

**Example**

suppose string given is **'abccbaad'**

Then, *sub-string will be 'abc' and its reverse will be 'cba'*

both exist in the given string.

how will you find both of them ?

please provide code snippets if possible.

**Note**: length of substring > 1

**update**: characters used in a substring from a position should not be used again in reversed string.

**For eg.** *suppose 'c' from index 2 is used in substring then, it again should not be used in reversed string but 'c' from index 3 is allowed.*

Comment: What programming language do you use?

Comment: @SalomonZhang  python

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want to find **all substrings whose reverse is also present in the given string**.

In that case, building on top of this answer  - [find all substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22470047/8505509) :

```
def get_all_substrings(input_string):
    output_strings = list()
    length = len(input_string)
    for i in xrange(length): # Iterate through all indices of the string
        for j in xrange(i + 1, length):  # Iterate through indices starting from i + 1 to end of the string, so as to obtain substrings of length > 1
            substr = input_string[i:j + 1] # Slice the substring
            if substr[::-1] in input_string: # Check if the substring's reverse exists in the original string
                output_strings.append(substr) # If it does, add it to a list
    return output_strings
print get_all_substrings("abccbaad") # Output - ['ab', 'abc', 'abcc', 'abccb', 'abccba', 'bc', 'bcc', 'bccb', 'bccba', 'cc', 'ccb', 'ccba', 'cb', 'cba', 'ba', 'aa']
```

Comment: Sry maybe I didn't clear my question but I have updated now ! Ty :)

Comment: @YaShChaudhary Please give a concrete example of the expected input and output, since I am unable to figure out the exact requirement of the question. A sample input string, and a sample output followed by an explanation of the reasoning behind the output should do.