# Program gives list of all potential substings from a given string, need to filter out substrings not in alphabetical order

Tags: python, string, alphabetical

I have a list of all possible substrings from a given string, I need to print just the substrings that are in alphabetical order.

```
s = 'abcabcd'

a = len(s)

for x in range(a):
    for y in range(x,a-1):
        print(s[x:y+2])
```

if I change to:

```
for x in range(a):
    for y in range(x,a-1):
        if s[y+1] >= s[y]:
            print(s[x:y+2])
```

I get the exact same answer, nothing is filtered out.

Current result is the following:

ab
abc
abca
abcab
abcabc
abcabcd
bc
bca
bcab
bcabc
bcabcd
ca
cab
cabc
cabcd
ab
abc
abcd
bc
bcd
cd

I'm looking for the result to be:

ab
abc
bc
ab
abc
abcd
bc
bcd
cd

Just substrings that are in alphabetical order.

Comment: when you say alphabetical order, do you mean only those substrings whose characters are in alphabetical sequence? e.g. from your example string `'abc'`, do expect to output only `'abc'`,`'abc'`, and `'bcd'`?

Comment: Yes dave that's what I'm looking for.  And thanks for the help on editing my question.  First timer on stackedoverflow and first week of learning Python.

Comment: The strings that would be left to print would be ab
abc
bc
ab
abc
abcd
bc
bcd
cd

Comment: ok great, please [`edit`](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22033632) the question and include that desired output in the question

Comment: What should be the output for `abcaef`? Should `ae` and `aef` be included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're printing the substring whenever you find a pair of characters that are in order, not testing *all* characters in the substring.

You can use the `all()` function to test whether the whole substring meets the requirement.

```
s = 'abcabcd'
a = len(s)
for x in range(a):
    for y in range(x+2, a+1):
        if all(s[z] < s[z+1] for z in range(x, y-1)):
            print(s[x:y])
```

Comment: Code in comments is impossible to read, and doesn't even work for Python because it's missing indentation.

Comment: It looks like it's the same as mine, except you add and subtract from indexes in different places.

Comment: Got it correct.  Yours was right, I just had the original range still in Python.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to generate all substrings and check if each substring is in the lowercase alphabet:

```
import string

sequence = string.ascii_lowercase

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469997/how-to-get-all-the-contiguous-substrings-of-a-string-in-python
all_substrings = [s[i:j+1] for i in xrange(a) for j in xrange(i,a)]

for substr in all_substrings:
    if substr in sequence and len(substr) > 1:
        print(substr)
```

output:

```
ab
abc
bc
ab
abc
abcd
bc
bcd
cd
```

Comment: This will only find substrings that are consecutive letters. If the input is `adea` it should print `ad`.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, I'm just basing my answer on [OP's requested output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54374595/program-gives-list-of-all-potential-substings-from-a-given-string-need-to-filte/54374747?noredirect=1#comment95563766_54374595)

Comment: All the letters that are in order in his example happen also to be consecutive.