# How to Know if a Complete Sentence has dates in it?

Tags: python, parsing

I have seen some posts that deal with recognizing if a possible string could be a date or not,but none of them seem to deal with if a sentence could have potential dates in it or not.

I have used the dateutil parser function which seems to be effective in recognizing dates in strings only if the date is the only component of the string.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

def is_date(string, fuzzy=False):
    """
    Return whether the string can be interpreted as a date.

    :param string: str, string to check for date
    :param fuzzy: bool, ignore unknown tokens in string if True
    """
    try: 
        parse(string, fuzzy=fuzzy)
        return True

    except ValueError:
        return False

>>> is_date("1990-12-1")
True
>>> is_date("foo 1990-12-1 bar")
False
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to split the string and then test each part, returning True if any of the split strings successfully parses to a date.

```
def is_date(string, fuzzy=False):
    """
    Return whether the string can be interpreted as a date.

    :param string: str, string to check for date
    :param fuzzy: bool, ignore unknown tokens in string if True
    """
    def parse_date(date_string):
        try: 
            return parse(date_string, fuzzy=fuzzy)
        except ValueError:
            return False

    return any(parse_date(s) for s in string.split())

>>> is_date("1990-12-1")
True

>>> is_date("foo 1990-12-1 bar")
True

>>> is_date("foo 1990-13-1 bar")
False

>>> is_date('Book by appt. for Dec. 31, 2019')
True  # Both 'Dec.' and '2019' successfully parse to a date.

# But be wary of false positives.
>>> is_date('I had 2019 hits on my website today')
True
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple regex pattern

```py
import re
def is_date(regex, str):
    return bool(re.match(regex, s))

regex = r'.*? \d{4}-\d\d?-\d\d? .*?'

>>> is_date(regex, "foo bar")
False
>>> is_date(regex, "1990-12-1")
True
>>> is_date(regex, "foo 1990-12-1 bar")
True
```

This will match any date in the format " ####-#[#]-#[#] " where the # in square brackets is optional. You can modify this regex pattern to suite your needs.

[more about regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to check all possible (continuous) substrings of the original string. That solution has horrible performance (N^2 calls to OP's `is_date`), but it does not rely on heuristics to split tokens in the string or regexp definitions: by definition, it matches iff `is_date` would have matched a substring.

```
def get_all_substrings(input_string):
    # From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469997/how-to-get-all-the-contiguous-substrings-of-a-string-in-python
    # could be made a generator to save space, but we are not making a performant solution anyway
    length = len(input_string)
    return [input_string[i:j+1] for i in xrange(length) for j in xrange(i,length)]

def contains_date(string):
    for substring in get_all_substrings(string):
        if is_date(substring): return True
    return False
```