# How to check if a string is in a longer string in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know it's quite straightforward to use `df.str.contains()` to check if the column contains a certain substring.

What if I want to do the other way around: check if the column's value **is contained** by a longer string? I did a search but couldn't find an answer. I thought this should be easy, like in pure python we could simply `'a' in 'abc'`

I tried to use `df.isin` but seems it's not designed for this purpose.

Say I have a df looks like this:

```
       col1      col2
0     'apple'    'one'
1     'orange'   'two'
2     'banana'   'three'
```

I want to query this df on `col1` if **is contained** by a string `appleorangefruits`, it should return me the first two rows.

Comment: Can you create [MCVE], that would explain a lot.

Comment: Is the longer string you want to check against a constant, or does it vary from case to case?

Comment: @harvpan thanks. added a simple example

Comment: @KevinTroythanks Kevin. It varies, for example, I have a column called ID in the df. But somehow the user provides me another format of ID which is a bit longer. I want to iterate the ID list to find out those matched rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `apply` is notoriously slow I thought I'd have a play with some other ideas.

If your "long_string" is relatively short and your DataFrame is massive, you could do something weird like this.

```
from itertools import combinations
from random import choice

# Create a large DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={'test' : [choice('abcdef') for i in range(10_000_000)]}
)

long_string = 'abcdnmlopqrtuvqwertyuiop'

def get_all_substrings(input_string):
    length = len(input_string)
    return [input_string[i:j + 1] for i in range(length) for j in range(i,length)]

sub_strings = get_all_substrings(long_string)

df.test.isin(sub_strings)
```

This ran in about 300ms vs 2.89s for the above `apply(lambda a: a in 'longer string')` answers. This is ten times quicker!

Note: I used the `get_all_substrings` functions from [How To Get All The Contiguous Substrings Of A String In Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22470047/4049396)

Answer (score 4):

You can call an apply on the column, i.e.:

```
df['your col'].apply(lambda a: a in 'longer string')
```

Answer (score 3):

You need:

```
longstring = 'appleorangefruits'
df.loc[df['col1'].apply(lambda x: x in longstring)]
```

Output:

```
    col1    col2
0   apple   one
1   orange  two
```

Answer (score 2):

If the string you are checking against is a constant, I believe you can achieve it by using `DataFrame.apply`:

`df.apply(lambda row: row['mycol'] in 'mystring', axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

try..

```
>>> df[df.col1.apply(lambda x: x in 'appleorangefruits')]
     col1 col2
0   apple  one
1  orange  two
```