# Nested FOR loops giving time out error for large string values - Python

Tags: python-3.x, nested-loops

I have to form several sub-strings from a single string.

Usual nested for loops with i and j is giving correct result but having time out issue for larger string values(>3K length).

Looking for comprehension or any other solution that might give quick results.

```
for i in range((len(string)+1)):
    for j in range(i+1, (len(string)+1)):
        substring_list.append(string[i:j])
```

Comment: does `substring_list = [string[i:j] for i in range(len(string)+1) for j in range(i+1, len(string)+1)]` go any faster? I wouldn't expect it to, since it's doing roughly the same amount of work, but it's a list comprehension of what you have there. I don't think you'll get overwhelmingly much of a performance improvement on this without really fancy `itertools` stuff, just because this many permutations on such a large string is a lot of work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To Get All The Contiguous Substrings Of A String In Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469997/how-to-get-all-the-contiguous-substrings-of-a-string-in-python)

Comment: if you are running on local just increase time limit