# All possible substring in Python

Tags: python, substring

Can anyone help me with finding all the possible substring in a string using python?

E.g:

```
string = 'abc'
```

output

```
a, b, c, ab, bc, abc
```

P.s : I am a beginner and would appreciate if the solution is simple to understand.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share your code.

Comment: So there cannot be `ac`? Thats kinda important

Comment: as of now i am able to find the substrings if its given by the user eg if i need to find cdc in ABCDCDC. for i in range(len(s1)): print(s1[i:i+3])

Comment: Check out [print substrings given string](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-print-substrings-given-string/)

Comment: Same question, but Python 2 so I wouldn't call it a duplicate: [How To Get All The Contiguous Substrings Of A String In Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22469997/4518341)

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like:

```
for length in range(len(string)):
    for index in range(len(string) - length):
        print(string[index:index+length+1])
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
ab
bc
abc
```

Answer (score 2):

else one way is using the [combinations](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

```
from itertools import combinations
s = 'abc'
[
    ''.join(x)
    for size in range(1, len(s) + 1)
    for x in  (combinations(s, size))
]
```

Out

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'ab', 'ac', 'bc', 'abc']
```

Comment: “ac” shouldn’t be on the list

Answer (score 0):

Every substring contains a unique start index and a unique end index (which is greater than the start index). You can use two for loops to get all unique combinations of indices.

```py
def all_substrings(s):
    all_subs = []
    for end in range(1, len(s) + 1):
        for start in range(end):
            all_subs.append(s[start:end])
    return all_subs
```

```py
s = 'abc'
print(all_substrings(s)) # prints ['a', 'ab', 'b', 'abc', 'bc', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like:

```
def subString(s):
    for i in range(len(s)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(s)+1):
            print(s[i:j])
```

> > > subString("aashu")
> > > a
> > > aa
> > > aas
> > > aash
> > > aashu
> > > a
> > > as
> > > ash
> > > ashu
> > > s
> > > sh
> > > shu
> > > h
> > > hu
> > > u