# How do you separate all possible substrings in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example lets say:

```
Str = "abc"
```

The desired output I am looking for is:

```
a, b, c, ab, bc, abc
```

so far I have:

```
#input
Str = input("Please enter a word: ")
#len of word
n = len(Str)
#while loop to seperate the string into substrings
for Len in range(1,n + 1):
   for i in range(n - Len + 1):
      j = i + Len - 1
      for k in range(i,j + 1):
          #printing all the substrings
          print(Str[k],end="")
```

this would get me:

```
abcabbcabc
```

which has all the correct substrings but not seperated. What do I do to get my desired output? I would think the `end=''` would do the trick in seperating each substring into each individual lines but it doesn't. Any suggestions?

Comment: put your results into a list and then print the list at the end `" ".join(my_list)` also, check out `itertools.permutations()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To Get All The Contiguous Substrings Of A String In Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469997/how-to-get-all-the-contiguous-substrings-of-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Or you can use `" "` (single space) instead of `""` (empty string).

Answer (score 2):

You could add an extra `print()` in the `i` loop, but it's easier to use a [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-slice) instead:

```
s = "abc"
n = len(s)
for size in range(1, n+1):
    for start in range(n-size+1):
        stop = start + size
        print(s[start:stop])
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
ab
bc
abc
```

On the other hand, if you want them literally joined on comma-spaces as you wrote, the simplest way is to save them in a list then join at the end.

```
s = "abc"
n = len(s)
L = []
for size in range(1, n+1):
    for start in range(n-size+1):
        stop = start + size
        L.append(s[start:stop])
print(*L, sep=', ')
```

Or, I would probably use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-list-comprehension) for this:

```
s = "abc"
n = len(s)
L = [s[j:j+i] for i in range(1, n+1) for j in range(n-i+1)]
print(*L, sep=', ')
```

Output:

```
a, b, c, ab, bc, abc
```

Answer (score 0):

a more pythonic solution

code:

```
import itertools
s = "abc"
for i in range(1,len(s)+1):
    print(["".join(word) for word in list(itertools.combinations(s,i))])
```

result:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
['ab', 'ac', 'bc']
['abc']
```

Comment: OP's looking for [chunks](/q/312443/4518341), not combinations, so `'ac'` shouldn't be there.